# Как написать скрипт , который реагирует на изменение значения?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно написать скрипт,  который реагирует на изменение значения input#font-size-slider (событие input) и обновляет инлайн-стиль span#text обновляя его свойство font-size. В результате при перетаскивании ползунка будет меняться размет текста.

```html
<input id="font-size-slider" type="range" />
<br />
<span id="text">Абракадабра!</span>
```

Comment: вы даже название события правильно написали, что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Я сейчас исправлю, а еще скину код свой

Comment: У меня не меняется размер текста при перетаскивании ползунка

Comment: ну покажите ваш код, возможно у вас просто какая-то опечатка

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста я бросила решение, вроде бы работает

Answer (score 3):

```js
const input = document.getElementById("font-size-slider");
const span = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("input", handleInputRange);
function handleInputRange(event) {
  span.style.fontSize = event.currentTarget.value + "px";
}
```

```html
<input id="font-size-slider" type="range" />
<br />
<span id="text">Абракадабра!</span>
```

Comment: вы молодец, все работает!

Comment: спасибо наверное нужно было написать просто сюда написать)))) Просто я еще учусь и ко мне часто приходит ступор)

Comment: ничего страшного, что вы сами же ответили на свой вопрос) Во-первых иногда это так и работает, во-вторых, ваш ответ может пригодиться кому-то еще

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает  + "px"?

Answer (score 1):

```
const inputRangeRef = document.querySelector("#font-size-control");
const inputTextRef = document.querySelector("#text");

const handleInput = () => {
  inputTextRef.style.fontSize = `${inputRangeRef.value}px`;
};

inputRangeRef.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
```